# Validate Cognito SMS_MFA code using aws sdk in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-js, multi-factor-authentication

I have react login page. When user enters username/password, request goes to backend and backend executes **signInUser** method as shown below.

---

NOTE:
If MFA is disabled for a user, it returns a set of tokens eg. AccessToken, RefreshToken, IdToken, I send these tokens to front-end and user then goes to dashboard. In short things work fine.

But if I enable MFA manually in cognito for the same user, **signInUser** will send a challenge called "**SMA_MFA**" and it sends following object,

```
{
    "ChallengeName": "SMS_MFA",
    "Session": "AYABeCMrhuH....",
    "ChallengeParameters": {
        "CODE_DELIVERY_DELIVERY_MEDIUM": "SMS",
        "CODE_DELIVERY_DESTINATION": "+91*******83",      //<<<<<<--------- I receive 6 digit code on my mobile with this response
        "USER_ID_FOR_SRP": "userA"
    }
}
```

---

**Cognito.Service.js**

```
this.cognitoIdentity = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider(this.config);

async signInUser(username, password, cb) {
    
    const params = {
      AuthFlow: "USER_PASSWORD_AUTH",
      ClientId: this.clientId,
      AuthParameters: {
        USERNAME: username,
        PASSWORD: password,
        SECRET_HASH: this.generateHash(username)
      }
    };

    try {
      this.cognitoIdentity.initiateAuth(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("signinUser: error", err);
        } 
        else {
          
           if (data?.ChallengeName === "SMS_MFA") {  //<--------- checking if SMA_MFA challenge, sending entire response object back to FE...
                return res.status(200).send(data);
            }

          console.log(data)
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Now, after receiving **SMA_MFA** challenge object in FE, I redirect user to a page where he can enter 6 digit code. Then clicking **verify** button makes a call to backend `api/verify-mfa-code`.

**Now in backend, I don't know how to verify MFA Code**....

**What I have tried as follow**,

```
async verifyMFACode(payload, cb) {
    try {
      const params = {
        Session: payload.Session,           //<<<<<-------- received session (token) that I received from FE (sent by backend to FE) as explained above
        UserCode: payload.userCode          //<<<<<-------- received 6 digit SMS code sent by FE
      }

      
      this.cognitoIdentity.verifySoftwareToken(params, (err, data) => {  //<<<<---- I don't know if I have to user verifySoftwareToken but tried with it.
        if (err) {
          console.log("refreshtoken initiateAuth error:", err)
          cb(err);
        } // an error occurred
        else {
          cb(null, data); // successful response
        }
      });
    } catch (err) {
      cb(err);
    }
  }
```

I get below error with verifySoftwareToken method,

> NotAuthorizedException: Invalid session for the user.

I really have no idea how to answer **SMA_Challenge** using Nodejs using aws-sdk.

**NOTE:** Somewhere people are sending **AccessToken** in **verifySoftwareToken** params but I don't get AccessToken because user is yet not signedIn and he has to pass the challenge first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`VerifySoftwareToken`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_VerifySoftwareToken.html) API is for [TOTP MFA](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-mfa-totp.html), not for SMS MFA.

You need to use the [`RespondToAuthChallenge`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_RespondToAuthChallenge.html) API () for validating SMS MFA codes.

---

For v2 of the JS SDK, here is a minimal example using the [`respondToAuthChallenge`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#respondToAuthChallenge-property) method:

```js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var client = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

const userPoolAppClientId = "";
const username = "";
const mfaCode = "";
const session = "";

var request = {
    ChallengeName: 'SMS_MFA', 
    ClientId: userPoolAppClientId,
    ChallengeResponses: {
        'USERNAME': username,
        'SMS_MFA_CODE': mfaCode,
        'SECRET_HASH': this.generateHash(username)
    },
    Session: session
};

client.respondToAuthChallenge(request, function(err, response) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
    else {
        var authenticationResult = {
            accessToken: response.AuthenticationResult.AccessToken,
            idToken: response.AuthenticationResult.IdToken,
            refreshToken: response.AuthenticationResult.RefreshToken,
        }

        console.log(authenticationResult);
    }
});
```

---

For v3 of the JS SDK, you need to use the [`RespondToAuthChallengeCommand`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/Package/-aws-sdk-client-cognito-identity-provider/Interface/RespondToAuthChallengeRequest/) JS SDK command.

Here's the same minimal example, compatible with v3:

```js
import {
    CognitoIdentityProviderClient,
    RespondToAuthChallengeCommand
} from "@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider";

const client = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient(config);

const userPoolAppClientId = "";
const username = "";
const mfaCode = "";
const session = "";

const request = {
    ChallengeName: "SMS_MFA",
    ClientId: userPoolAppClientId,
    ChallengeResponses: {
        "USERNAME": username,
        "SMS_MFA_CODE": mfaCode,
        'SECRET_HASH': this.generateHash(username)
    },
    Session: session,
};

const command = new RespondToAuthChallengeCommand(request);

const response = await client.send(command);

const authenticationResult = {
    accessToken: respondToAuthChallengeResponse.AuthenticationResult.AccessToken,
    idToken: respondToAuthChallengeResponse.AuthenticationResult.IdToken,
    refreshToken: respondToAuthChallengeResponse.AuthenticationResult.RefreshToken,
}

console.log(authenticationResult);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it seems you are using different packages. I use oly aws-sdk. I can't import `@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider`. However with the help of your answer I came to know I might need to use `adminRespondToAuthChallenge` but it throws `AccessDeniedException: User is not authorized to perform: cognito-idp:AdminRespondToAuthChallenge`

Comment: Yes it is 2.xxx.x.

Comment: Yeah you can update your answer but help me on AccessDeninedException error. Which policy do I need to add ?

Comment: @micronyks I've updated my answer to include an example for V2 as well - you don't need to use `adminRespondToAuthChallenge`. Please try the above code example.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the help...